# Applying a sale or discount to all products in Drupal's Ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'd like to temporarily apply a discount, in the form of a percentage, to all of the Products in my Ubercart store.  It would be especially helpful, but not necessary, if this could also vary based on a Product's field.

Comment: I previously suggested the Ubercart Discounts (Alternative) module but it recently prevented my store from functioning properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Ubercart Discount Coupons](https://drupal.org/project/uc_coupon) module can provide coupon discounts and the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module can be used to apply it automatically.